# How to iterate though a list of words and replace certain letters with words

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to iterate through a list of several words. If a certain letter is present it will replace that letter and add a word to the existing word. But it will only work on words in the list that have that letter.

```
list1 = ['06h', '12d', '05h', '04s', '12s', '12c']
#list2 = list(x+'sample' for x in cards)

or 

for x in cards:
    if 's' in x:
        cards.append('ample')[0]
```

This will add 'sample' to everything, i dont know how to make it only add 'sample' to cells with the letter "s".

```
list1 = [06h', '12d', '05h', '04s', '12s', '12c']
if "s" in list1:
```

Should show

```
list2 = [06h', '12d', '05h', '04sample', '12sample', '12c']
```

Comment: Did you attempt this at all? Also, any reason you're missing an opening quote in all 3 lists?

Comment: I have tried for a couple hours now. The opening quote is missing because i shortened my actual list for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comprehension checking if the strings ends in `s`:

```
>>> list1 = ['06h', '12d', '05h', '04s', '12s', '12c']
>>> [x + 'ample' if x.endswith('s') else x for x in list1]
['06h', '12d', '05h', '04sample', '12sample', '12c']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use find and can replace with samples

```
list1 = ['06h', '12d', '05h', '04s', '12s', '12c']
l2=[]
for item in list1:
    if item.find('s'):
        l2.append(item.replace('s','samples'))
    else:
        l2.append(item)
print(l2)

['06h', '12d', '05h', '04samples', '12samples', '12c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   list2 =[]
   for x in list1:
         if 's' in x:
            x = x.replace('s', 'sample')
         list2.add(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x: x.replace('s','sample'), list1)
```

would work as well.  map applies a function to  every element of a list and returns a list of the results.

Python is full of tools for working with lists.